# Multi-tenant, multi-database tenant testing in Laravel, access denied for dynamic MySQL users?

Tags: php, laravel, tenancy

I'm working on an app that uses the [stancl/tenancy](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy) (v3.7.2) package for Laravel, and I'm having difficulty getting my tenant-specific tests to run successfully.

The tenants are using the [PermissionControlledMySQLDatabaseManager](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy/blob/3.x/assets/config.php#L69) which handles creating and deleting databases/users/passwords for multi-database tenancy. I have an observer on the Tenant model that automatically creates these credentials at the time a tenant is created, as per the [documentation for those fields](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/tenant-attribute-encryption):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers\Central;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Central\Tenant;

class TenantObserver
{
    public function creating(Tenant $tenant): void
    {
        if (!$tenant->tenancy_db_username) {
            $tenant->tenancy_db_username = config('tenancy.database.prefix') . Str::random();
        }

        if (!$tenant->tenancy_db_password) {
            $tenant->tenancy_db_password = Str::password();
        }
    }
}
```

My `TestCase.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use App\Models\Central\Tenant;
use Database\Seeders\Central\Local\LocalStripeSeeder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->seed(LocalStripeSeeder::class);

        config(['tenancy.database.prefix' => 'testing_t_']);
    }

    protected function createTenant(array $data = []): Tenant
    {
        return Tenant::factory($data)->create();
    }
}
```

Then I have a `TenantTestCase.php` for tenant-specific tests, which creates a tenant and configures the tenant subdomain:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests;

use App\Models\Central\Tenant;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyBySubdomain;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\PreventAccessFromCentralDomains;

abstract class TenantTestCase extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected $tenancy = true;
    protected ?Tenant $tenant = null;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        if ($this->tenancy) {
            $this->initializeTenancy();

            $this->withoutMiddleware([
                InitializeTenancyBySubdomain::class,
                PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
            ]);

            // Login as superuser
            auth()->loginUsingId(1);
        }
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        if($this->tenancy) {
            $this->tenant->delete();
            DB::purge('tenant');
        }

        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function initializeTenancy(): void
    {
        $this->tenant = $this->createTenant();

        tenancy()->initialize($this->tenant);
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting MySQL errors among the lines of:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'testing_t_YhIAxUn1z5L3y3qB'@'172.26.0.5' (using password: YES) (Connection: tenant, SQL: select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`)
```

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'testing_t_vOq3OyUijOEYSBL5'@'172.26.0.5' (using password: YES) (Connection: tenant, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'testing_t_1f6c5c17-0e8d-40aa-9b3e-e89296db6766' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by table_name)
```

It's creating the users and the databases fine, so I'm not sure what the deal is with the access denied error is or why it's so sporadic. The tenancy creation/initialization happens synchronously in my testing environment, and I can confirm that for each test, the connection is correct. I'm using Pest, so I added a `beforeEach()` hook to check the connection credentials, the current tenant and the database tables using the `DB` facade:

```php
beforeEach(function (): void {
    // accessProtected is a method in Pest.php that
    // uses Reflection to access the $config property
    Log::debug('Connection credentials', [accessProtected(DB::connection(), 'config')]);
    Log::debug('Using tenant:', [
        'id' => $this->tenant->id,
        'tenancy_db_username' => $this->tenant->tenancy_db_username,
        'tenancy_db_password' => $this->tenant->tenancy_db_password,
        'tenancy_db_name' => $this->tenant->tenancy_db_name
    ]);
    $databaseName = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    $tableNames = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
    $prefixedTableNames = array_map(function($tableName) use ($databaseName) {
        return $databaseName . '.' . $tableName;
    }, $tableNames);

    Log::debug('Database tables:', $prefixedTableNames);
});
```

And I get a correct set of log entries for each test:

```
[2024-01-02 18:46:49] testing.DEBUG: Connection credentials [{
    "driver": "mysql",
    "host": "mariadb",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831",
    "username": "testing_t_9RQLr9tzdZM3ZPtJ",
    "password": "Ii[UUQeO;OGq9S)m,Yv}5E~!CN~LlS53",
    "unix_socket": "",
    "charset": "utf8mb4",
    "collation": "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
    "prefix": "",
    "prefix_indexes": true,
    "strict": true,
    "engine": null,
    "options": [],
    "name": "tenant"
}] 
[2024-01-02 18:46:49] testing.DEBUG: Using tenant: {
    "id": "ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831",
    "tenancy_db_username": "testing_t_9RQLr9tzdZM3ZPtJ",
    "tenancy_db_password": "Ii[UUQeO;OGq9S)m,Yv}5E~!CN~LlS53",
    "tenancy_db_name":"testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831"
} 
[2024-01-02 18:46:49] testing.DEBUG: Database tables: [
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.migrations",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.model_has_permissions",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.model_has_roles",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.permissions",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.roles",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.role_has_permissions",
    "testing_t_ecfa2b8d-28ce-40ef-863a-634b53f94831.users"
]
```

So the `DB` facade is able to access the correct database, but within the test it's not? I was also able to verify that the correct `tenant()` is present within the test.

It also doesn't seem to call the delete method properly when there's errors, and this is also sporadic. For example, I have a tenant test file that runs 3 tests to check for API rate limiting based on the limits of the plan that the tenant is subscribed to. Sometimes only one of those tests triggers the logging to file and properly deletes the database, but the other two will leave the database and user and it results in having a ton of extras that I have to manually go in and drop:

[image: Excess databases]

The grants are correct, if I check them with `SHOW GRANTS FOR [user]` on one of the leftover users, I get these (as expected):

[image: MySQL user grants]

I've been banging my head on this for days now and can't get the tests to pass consistently. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I was able to get my tests to reliably pass by removing the dynamic MySQL user/password creating, and using the root login for testing. However, this does not mimic production app behavior and would much rather prefer to keep things as close as possible to how they would be in the actual application.

In my `TenantTestCase.php`, I modified the runtime configuration in `setUp()` to use the standard `MySQLDatabaseManager`:

```php
config([
    'tenancy.database.prefix' => 'testing_t_',
    'tenancy.database.managers.mysql' => MySQLDatabaseManager::class,
]);
```

then call `$this->initializeTenancy()`, where I set the username/password

```php
$this->tenant = $this->createTenant([
    'tenancy_db_username' => config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
    'tenancy_db_password' => config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
]);
```

[Full gist explanation for the latest iteration](https://gist.github.com/rjp2525/25ebf3338750d95247fc5b0192f8df51)

Comment: Interesting question. Can it be something like that the user cannot access that database on that particular host? I would dd the credentials (somehow) and then access the database through the command line. Is this something you can share through github? It might be easier to look at this that way

Comment: I don't believe so. This is locally through docker, so I don't think it's a connection issue since the tests sometimes pass and there's no issue. It's really random - I can extract some more of the relevant parts into a gist and add that to my question in the morning. It's proving to be a little difficult to get the credentials on the connection (since the tenancy initializes afterwards, it's showing root user/db)

Comment: Investigate if there’s a pattern to when these errors occur. It might give insights into whether it’s a timing issue or a configuration problem. After each test, especially when databases are dynamically created and deleted, check that the database connections are properly reset. You can use DB::purge('tenant'); to clear the tenant connection. The deletion of databases and users might be happening asynchronously. Confirm that your tests wait for these operations to complete before proceeding to the next test. Use Queue::fake(); and Queue::assertPushed(); to manage and test asynchronous jobs.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I just updated the question with more detail, but I am at a loss here at this point. I added some additional debugging checks before each test runs and I'm able to access the tenant database/show all tables on it, as well as get the current test tenant instance. Those jobs for deleting and creating also happen synchronously in my test suite. It's very sporadic

Comment: @Winter add some error logging to TenantObserver and TenantTestCase

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $databaseName.* TO '$username'@'localhost';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: @Winter try to add a sleep(5) after tenant creation and before the initialization.
I think that the mysql needs some time to complete the configuration for new user, I have similar issue with dynamically created database, received the error "Unknown database", and the sleep some seconds resolved the issue.

Comment: @HrahatTahmazyan you need to write your answer in full so it can be voted as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem whenever I try running all the tests in parallel. In my base TestCase class `tests/TestCase.php` I have this `public ?string $parallelToken;` to keep the current token if I am running the tests in parallel. Below is a snippet of my `setUp()`

```php
protected function setUp(): void
{
    if (!defined('TEST_START_TIME')) {
        define('TEST_START_TIME', microtime(true));
    }

    parent::setUp();

    $this->parallelToken = null;

    if ($token = ParallelTesting::token()) {
        $this->parallelToken = $token;
    }
```

and then I additionally created a method to know when it is being run in the parallel context

```php
public function isRunningParallely(): bool
{
    return $this->parallelToken ? true : false;
}
```

and now following [Hrahat Tahmazyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13237203/hrahat-tahmazyan) advice, I noticed mysql/mariadb needs a second or two to apply configurations for the newly created user, so I do this in some of the tests immediately after creating a new tenant.

```php
$cm = $this->createMerchant($uuid);

if ($this->isRunningParallely()) {
    sleep(2);
}
```

This has enabled all tests to run parallely without issues. Below is an image showing this.
[image: Tests Running In Parallel]